# How can I filter a queryset inside a django form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to add chat functionality to my app and right now I can add users to existing chats but what I need to do is filter users that are not already in the chat in the form.
I'm using django form with passed arguments to filter my users but I'm not getting any results.
My Chat model has a m2m field to user called '*users*' and my User has a m2m field called '*friends*' with itself.

**forms.py**

```
class AddUserToChatForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Chat
        fields = ('users', )

    def __init__(self, chat, friends, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        self.chat = chat
        self.friends = friends
        super(AddUserToChatForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['users'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=self.request.user.friends.exclude(user__in=chat.users.all()),
                                                              widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
                                                              (attrs={'class': 'add-people-to-chat-form'}),
                                                              label='Friends:')
```

**views.py**

```
def add_users_to_chat(request, pk):
    chat = Chat.objects.get(pk=pk)
    friends = request.user.friends.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddUserToChatForm(chat, friends, request, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            users_to_add = form.cleaned_data['users']
            chat.users.add(*users_to_add)
            chat.save()
            return redirect('messages')
    else:
        form = AddUserToChatForm(chat, friends, request, instance=None)
    return render(request, 'add_users_to_chat.html', {'form': form, 'chat': chat, 'friends': friends})
```

**EDIT**

Looks like my *exclude* statement has no effect because when I switch it to *filter* the set returns all of the user friends.

**UPDATE**

I was able to retreive the required users using difference method like this:
in view:

```
chat = Chat.objects.get(pk=pk)
friends = request.user.friends.all()
chat_users = chat.users.all()
queryset = friends.difference(chat_users)
```

and pass it to the form

```
def __init__(self, queryset, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = request
    self.queryset = queryset
    super(AddUserToChatForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['users'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=self.queryset,
                                                          widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
                                                          (attrs={'class': 'add-people-to-chat-form'}),
                                                          label='Friends:')
```

getting users with *difference* method but now when I try to submit the form I get this error: **Calling QuerySet.filter() after difference() is not supported.**

Debugger quits execution on this line in view:

```
users_to_add = form.cleaned_data['users']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the wanted result by querying using *exclude* after all:

in view:

```
queryset = friends.exclude(id__in=chat_users)
```

and now everything works as intended

Answer (score 0):

As the fields are automatically generated by the ModelForm, it is best to define only the a queryset in init:

```
def __init__(self, chat, friends, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = request
    self.chat = chat
    self.friends = friends
    super(AddUserToChatForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['users'].queryset = self.request.user.friends.exclude(user__in=chat.users.all())
```